# Why is it necessary to specify length of a column in a table

Tags: limit

I always wonder why should we limit a column length in a database table to some limit then the default one.
Eg. I have a column short_name in my table People the default length is 255 characters for the column but I restrict it to 100 characters. What difference will it make.

Answer (score 0):

The string will be truncated to the maximum length ( in characters usually ).

Answer (score 0):

The way it is actually implemented is up to the database engine you use.

For example:

- CHAR(30) will always use up 30 characters in MySQL, and this allows
  MySQL to speed up access because it is able to predict the value
  length without parsing anything;
- VARCHAR(30) will trim any lengthy strings to 30 characters in MySQL when strict mode is on, otherwise you may use longer strings and they will be fully stored;
- In SQLite, you can store strings in any type of column, ignoring the type.

The reason many features of SQL are supported in those database engines eventhough they are not being utilized, or being utilized in different ways, is in order to maintain compliance to the SQL schema.